# what is the difference between using int and <int>

Tags: c++, int, stack

I recently started learning about stacks in C++. While looking at an example, I noticed they used the following:

```
       void showstack(stack <int> s).
```

I was wondering what the `<>` did, and how is it different from just using `int`?

Comment: Looks like you need [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), particularly the chapter about templates

Comment: Well, `stack int s` is a syntax error. That's one way they're different.

Comment: yes, my compiler did not like it when i removed the <> part.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking at are [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

Basically, `stack` is a template, declared (in a simplified manner) like this:

```
template <class T>
class stack { /*...*/ };
```

Thus, `stack` is not a class, you cannot talk about a *stack type*. It will only become a type once the template parameter is specified; for example: `stack<int>` is a *stack of integers* in this case.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I could not find anything online about it, but now that i know what they are i will read about it.

Comment: I recommend starting with one of the books in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1673776). You will get a much better view over the concepts of C++. C++ is the language that can do anything and everything :). Also, if you found my answer useful, please do not forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[`stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack#targetText=The%20std%3A%3Astack%20class,set%20of%20functions%20is%20provided.) just like many other containers is [templated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates). You need to specify the type of elements you are going to store in the container.

```
template<
    class T, // this what you specified in your code
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

There is no stack compiled in your code until you use one with a type, like you did.

Answer (score 0):

It says that `showstack`'s parameter is a `stack` of `ints`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<>` are used for templates, which tell a class what kind of data to expect. You could replace `int` with `string` and you would have a stack of strings that way.

[For more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)